# WinAPI CreateWindow function creates smaller windows than set

Tags: c++, winapi, screenshot

My task is to recreate application with features similar to these of Windows' snipping tool. One of them is capturing a screenshot of a window that is currently active and that's what causes me problems. Everything is almost perfectly fine, however "snip" taken of an app is bigger than the actual app by few pixels and that's because it's window is slightly smaller than I set it to be.

Here's my CreateWindow call for the main window I test it on:

```
hwnd = CreateWindow(TEXT("Klasa okien"), TEXT("Screenshot"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 
        10, 10, 350, 400, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

then procedure of gathering information about that very window's size and proceeding to "taking snip" function:

```
RECT okno;
HWND aktywne = GetForegroundWindow();
GetWindowRect(aktywne, &okno);
CaptureScreen(okno.left, okno.top, okno.right-okno.left, okno.bottom-okno.top);
```

Finally part of the function that takes these snips:

```
void CaptureScreen(int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
    HDC hDc = CreateCompatibleDC(0);
    HBITMAP hBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(GetDC(0), width, height);
    SelectObject(hDc, hBmp);
    BitBlt(hDc, 0, 0, width, height, GetDC(0), x, y, SRCCOPY);
    Bitmap *p_bmp = Bitmap::FromHBITMAP(hBmp, NULL);
...
```

and as I said - everything is almost fine and the picture that is being created is in fact 350x400 BUT actual window's size seems to be 336x393. I'm also attaching two pictures - the perfectly snipped one is the one created by Windows' tool and the other one is mine.

[Result of my tool 350x400](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfI64.png) and
[Result of Windows' snipping tool 336x393](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnuY2.jpg)

Comment: Can't test atm, but you may want to look into [this function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632665(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: `BUT actual window's size seems to be 336x393` -- How are you determining this?

Comment: Is this another case of the common question of "Windows 10 lies about window sizes for programs that do not have a special manifest"?

Comment: @CareyGregory, if I'll launch Windows' snipping tool and choose an option to "Window snip" my app - it will create an image with size 336x393. I've also attached an exact result of such operation. The problem is that I've actually passed 350 and 400 as a size to CreateWindow() function.

Comment: @Joachim, I'll try that now. Thanks!

Comment: @andlabs, I'm not sure. I don't think I'm experienced enough to have an answer for your question. I don't mind my window being slightly smaller than I set it to be. I'd like to be able to take a screenshot that would not include area out of window's bounds.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This issue is Windows 10 specific, it has to do with Windows 10 transparent borders. If for example window has re-sizing borders, then the borders on left/right/bottom are about 7 pixels.

If you are taking screen shot then you may wish to exclude the transparent borders. Replace `GetWindowRect` with:

```
DwmGetWindowAttribute(hwnd, DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS, &rc, sizeof(RECT)); 
//requires at least Windows Vista
```

Compared to `GetWindowRect`, the rectangle obtained from `DwmGetWindowAttribute` could be smaller by about 7 pixels on left, right, and bottom.

```
#include "Dwmapi.h"
#pragma comment( lib, "Dwmapi.lib" )
...

RECT rc;
DwmGetWindowAttribute(hwnd, DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS, &rc, sizeof(RECT));
int w = rc.right - rc.left;
int h = rc.bottom - rc.top;

HDC memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
HBITMAP bmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, w, h);
SelectObject(memdc, bmp);
BitBlt(memdc, 0, 0, w, h, hdc, rc.left, rc.top, CAPTUREBLT | SRCCOPY);
...
```

Secondly, don't use `GetDC(0)` (in that way), because it causes resource leak. You must save the handle obtained from `GetDC` and release it later. For example:

```
HWND desktopWnd = GetDesktopWindow();
HDC hdc = GetDC(desktopWnd);
...
ReleaseDC(desktopWnd, hdc);
```

---

Edit:
or use

```
HDC hdc = GetDC(0);
...
ReleaseDC(0, hdc);
```

Comment: GetDC(0) is perfectly fine. The leak is not because 0 was passed.

Comment: Yes, I updated the answer to make it more clear. Or maybe use `HWND_DESKTOP` instead of 0, so the code is more readable.

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what makes it work as intended. Thanks for that and that additional tip - I fixed it for more clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Before CreateWindow() call AdjustWindowRectEx():

```
int x = 10;
int y = 10;
int w = 350;
int h = 400;

RECT rect;
rect.left   = x;
rect.top    = y;
rect.right  = x + w;
rect.bottom = y + h;

UINT style = WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW;

AdjustWindowRectEx( &rect, style, 0, 0 );

hwnd = CreateWindow(
         TEXT("Klasa okien"), TEXT("Screenshot"), style, 
         rect.left, rect.top, rect.right-rect.left, rect.bottom-rect.top, 
         NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL
       );
```

[AdjustWindowRectEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-adjustwindowrectex)